# Python CVXPY kronecker product dimensions

Tags: python, cvxpy

I am trying to optimize using cvxpy.

```
w=cvxpy.Variable((10,1))

cvxpy.kron(w,w)
```

this is not working saying that first argument should be constant,

and then I tried to use numpy

```
numpy.kron(w,w)
```

and then, it says that incompatible dimensions (10,1) (10,1)

shouldn't it work?? How should I do the kronecker product on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using numpy operations on cvxpy Variables. Instead you should be using cvxpy [atoms](https://www.cvxpy.org/api_reference/cvxpy.atoms.html) whenever they are available. With numpy you can do the following:

```
numpy.kron(numpy.ones((10, 1)), numpy.ones((10, 1)))
```

As for the error, cvxpy is telling you that you cannot use a Variable as the first argument to `cvxpy.kron`. For example you can use a numpy array or a `cvxpy.Parameter`.

```
cvxpy.kron(numpy.ones((2, 2)), w)
```

Results in:

```
Expression(AFFINE, UNKNOWN, (20, 2))
```